# How to enable ECS service discovery by ecs-cli?

Tags: amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I want to use the functionality of [ECS Service Discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/news/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/).

I use `ecs-cli` for lanunching ECS with Fargate launch type.
However, I read the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli) of `ecs-cli` and cannot find any information.

Does anyone know about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure ECS to use Route 53

You will have to follow the guides located here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/overview-service-discovery.html

Comment: seems we need to create namespace and service without ecs-cli. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle service discovery is to use AWS ALB attachment to ECS.

1. Create an ALB and a Target Group
2. Provide the target group name in ECS service.
3. The service will identify the Container port mapping and attach it to the target group.

The above method is the recommended method from AWS. Hope this answers your question